# How to Fix Code to Avoid Stubnames Error (Python Pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas

```
dt = {'id': {0: 'x1', 1: 'x2', 2: 'x3', 3: 'x4', 4: 'x5', 5: 'x6', 6: 'x7', 7: 'x8', 8: 'x9', 9: 'x10'}, 'trt': {0: 'cnt', 1: 'cnt', 2: 'tr', 3: 'tr', 4: 'tr', 5: 'cnt', 6: 'tr', 7: 'tr', 8: 'cnt', 9: 'cnt'}, 'work.T1': {0: 0.6516556669957936, 1: 0.567737752571702, 2: 0.1135089821182191, 3: 0.5959253052715212, 4: 0.3580499750096351, 5: 0.4288094183430075, 6: 0.0519033221062272, 7: 0.2641776674427092, 8: 0.3987907308619469, 9: 0.8361341434065253}, 'play.T1': {0: 0.8647212258074433, 1: 0.6153524168767035, 2: 0.7751098964363337, 3: 0.3555686913896352, 4: 0.4058499720413238, 5: 0.7066469138953835, 6: 0.8382876652758569, 7: 0.2395891312044114, 8: 0.7707715332508087, 9: 0.3558977444190532}, 'talk.T1': {0: 0.5355970377568156, 1: 0.0930881295353174, 2: 0.169803041499108, 3: 0.8998324507847428, 4: 0.4226376069709658, 5: 0.7477464678231627, 6: 0.8226525799836963, 7: 0.9546536463312804, 8: 0.6854445093777031, 9: 0.5005032296758145}, 'work.T2': {0: 0.2754838624969125, 1: 0.2289039448369294, 2: 0.0144339059479534, 3: 0.7289645625278354, 4: 0.2498804717324674, 5: 0.1611832766793668, 6: 0.0170426501426845, 7: 0.4861003451514989, 8: 0.1029001718852669, 9: 0.8015470046084374}, 'play.T2': {0: 0.3543280649464577, 1: 0.9364325392525644, 2: 0.2458663922734558, 3: 0.4731414613779634, 4: 0.191560871200636, 5: 0.5832219698932022, 6: 0.4594731898978352, 7: 0.467434047954157, 8: 0.3998325555585325, 9: 0.5052855962421745}, 'talk.T2': {0: 0.0318881559651345, 1: 0.1144675880204886, 2: 0.468935475917533, 3: 0.3969867376144975, 4: 0.8336191941052675, 5: 0.7611217433586717, 6: 0.5733564489055425, 7: 0.447508045937866, 8: 0.0838020080700516, 9: 0.2191385473124683}}

mydt = pd.DataFrame(dt, columns = ['id', 'trt', 'work.T1', '', 'play.T1', 'talk.T1','work.T2', '', 'play.T2', 'talk.T2'])
```

So I have the above dataset and need to tidy it up. I have used the following code but it returns "`ValueError: stubname can't be identical to a column name.`" How can I fix the code to avoid this problem?

```
names = ['play', 'talk', 'work']

activities = pd.wide_to_long(dt, stubnames=names, i='id', j='time', sep='.', suffix='T\d').sort_index().reset_index()

activities
```

Note: I am trying to get the dataframe to look like the following.

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: your sample data work with your code

Answer (score 1):

Changed :

```
activities = pd.wide_to_long(activities, stubnames=names, i='id', j='time', sep='.', suffix='T\d').sort_index().reset_index()
```

To:

```
activities = pd.wide_to_long(mydt, stubnames=names, i='id', j='time', sep='.', suffix='T\d').sort_index().reset_index()
```

and then it works.